# regex to match one of the multiple strings followed by another string

Tags: regex, grep

I need a regex to match `any character(s) followed by foo. or bar. followed by anything followed by is.a.server followed by anything`.

e.g:

```
"foo.lnx station is.a.server" # match this
"my bar.unx node is.a.server.and.client" # match this
"baz station is.a.server" # do NOT not match this
"foo.lnx station not.a.server" # do NOT not match this, b'cos it don't match "is.a.server"
"foo.l is.a.server.linux" # match this
```

I have a variable `match_for="foo\|bar"`

```
$ echo "foo.lnx station is.a.server
my bar.unx node is.a.server.and.client
baz station is.a.server
foo.lnx station not.a.server
foo.l is.a.server.linux" | grep "$match_for\\." | grep "is\.a\.server"
```

Above command with multiple `grep` works good, outputs:

```
foo.lnx station is.a.server
my bar.unx node is.a.server.and.client
foo.l is.a.server.linux
```

I am looking for a single regex (single `grep`) as below:

```
$ echo "foo.lnx station is.a.server
> my bar.unx node is.a.server.and.client
> baz station is.a.server
> foo.lnx station not.a.server
> foo.l is.a.server.linux" | grep "($match_for)\..*is\.a\.server.*"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming GNU `grep`.

Use POSIX ERE, `-E` option, do not escape pipe:

```sh
match_for='foo|bar'
echo "foo.lnx station is.a.server
my bar.unx node is.a.server.and.client
baz station is.a.server
foo.lnx station not.a.server
foo.l is.a.server.linux" | grep -E "($match_for)\..*is\.a\.server"
```

Or, with POSIX BRE:

```sh
match_for='foo\|bar'
echo "foo.lnx station is.a.server
my bar.unx node is.a.server.and.client
baz station is.a.server
foo.lnx station not.a.server
foo.l is.a.server.linux" | grep "\($match_for\)\..*is\.a\.server"
```

**Results**:

```sh
foo.lnx station is.a.server
my bar.unx node is.a.server.and.client
foo.l is.a.server.linux
```

Comment: Note: The [POSIX BRE standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03) doesn't specify support for alternation. Some implementations support it (with `\|`), but it's not actually part of the standard.

Answer (score 2):

If you have grep available then you also have awk available. Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
awk '/(foo|bar)\..*is\.a\.server/' file
```

or if part of the regexp has to be from a shell variable then:

```
match_for='foo|bar'
awk -v mf="$match_for" '$0 ~ (mf"\\..*is\\.a\\.server")'
```